# How to I create a new file with php Post Data

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on this website(for minecraft servers) that when you enter in a few things about your server, it will upload the info onto the list of servers. The thing is, I am a complete noob at PhP.
Here is my form code:
http://pastie.org/8061636
And here is my php code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['sName'];
$ip = $_POST['sIp'];
$port = $_POST['sPort'];
$desc = $_POST['sDesc'];
$finalName = $ip."(".$port.").txt";

$file = fopen($finalName, "w");
$size = filesize($finalName);

if($_POST['submit']) fwrite($file, "$name, $ip, $port, $desc");

header( 'Location: http://www.maytagaclasvegas.com/uniqueminecraftservers/upload/' ) ;
?>
```

Now what I am trying to do it get do is create a new file name using $ip and $port, and put this into a table. Can anyone help a newbie out? Thanks

Comment: why don't just create a record in a table with $name, $ip, $port, $desc fields

Comment: *sidenote:* remember to call `exit;` after `header('Location: $url');`

Comment: Tip: Instead of `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`, used `file_put_contents()` instead.

Comment: We **Awesome People**, would sure like to get a bit of feedback, *son*.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 file_put_contents("/path/to/files/".$ip."-".$port.".dat",
                   $_POST['sName'].",".$_POST['sIp'].",".$_POST['sPort'].",".
                   $_POST['sDesc']);
```

Then to create your table you would need to do something like this.

```
  $files = glob("/path/to/files/*.dat");
  echo "<table>";
  foreach($files as $file){
    echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", explode(",",file_get_contents($file),4))."</td></tr>";  
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

It would be a lot safer though to just use a database.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `implode(",", $_POST)` because you can't predict the order of the elements of the array.

Comment: where is the putting to table part?

Comment: @Barmar Answer updated to reflect this fact, and fixed the omited explode statement on the file contents.

Comment: @Orangepill Looks like the OP had to "go to bed".

Comment: @Orangepill Night owl too eh?

Comment: @Fred Crunch Time ... and yes

Comment: @Orangepill I know the feeling. It's hard to go to bed, when you don't want to let the "script" *win*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['sName'];
$ip = $_POST['sIp'];
$port = $_POST['sPort'];
$desc = $_POST['sDesc'];
$finalName = $ip."(".$port.").txt";

if($_POST['submit']) {
  $file = $finalName;
  // Append a new person to the file
  $content = "$name, $ip, $port, $desc";
  // Write the contents back to the file
  file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

Note: Be sure you have write (may be 777 in linux) permission on your folder where you are saving the file.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend 777, more like 644 for files, and 755 for folders. Plus you're missing line breaks. It's going to be bunched up, once the data starts rolling in like oranges. Something to the affect of `."\n"` will work, maybe even a `<br>`. I'm sure you'll figure it out. ;-)